# Nginx configuration changes are not taking place although nginx start, stop, reload is working fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I have a working nginx setup on AWS.

foo.domain.com is already mapped to a django server.

**I am trying to change url from foo.domain.com to foo777.domain.com.**

**But after succesful nginx stop, reload, start the new url is not coming into effect. Nginx continues to serve old url foo.domain.com instead of foo777.domain.com**

Here is what I have done so far.
I change all the instances of word foo to foo777 in /etc/nginx/sites-available/foo which is symlinked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo. I can open the symlinked file in vi and verify that changes (foo->foo777) are succesffuly done in config.

```
sudo service nginx stop && sudo service nginx reload && sudo service nginx start
 * Stopping nginx nginx                                                                                                                 [ OK ] 
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx                                                                                                  [ OK ] 
 * Starting nginx nginx                                                                                                                 [ OK ]
```

But the nginx is still serving foo.domain.com instead of foo777.domain.com

I can do sudo service nginx stop and foo.domain.com is successfully stopped; checked from browser.

I can do sudo service nginx start and foo.domain.com is successfully started; checked from browser.

For sake of completeness I do sudo service nginx reload and that gets successfully done without errors

I did sudo nginx -t and it reports

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I did which nginx and it reports

```
/usr/sbin/nginx
```

I did nginx -V and it reports:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.2.6 (Ubuntu)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --with-pcre-jit --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.2.6/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.2.6/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.2.6/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.2.6/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
```

The /etc/nginx/nginx.conf looks like this:

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
    }

    http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo looks like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  foo777.domain.com www.foo777.domain.com;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/domain.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/domain.error.log;
    root /home/user/foo/;

    location  /static/ {
        alias  /home/user/foo/static/;
    }

    location  / {
        proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8700;
        proxy_redirect        off;
        proxy_set_header      Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout    7200;
        client_max_body_size  10m;
    }

    allow all;
}
```

Everything seems normal and no error is reported anywhere except that foo777.domain.com is not being served.

I have restarted the AWS instance too but didn't affect anything either. Nginx continues to serve the old url.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

__

@tedder42

Edit 1:

Pasting the output of various diagnostic commands:

Command 1:

```
atd@atd-ub14:~$ curl -D - http://foo777.domain.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foo777.domain.com
```

Command 1 after some time:

```
atd@atd-ub14:~$ curl -D - http://foo777.domain.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to foo777.domain.com port 80: Connection timed out
```

Commmand2:

```
atd@atd-ub14:~$ curl -D - http://foo.domain.com
HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Server: nginx/1.2.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 06:38:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://foo.domain.com/login
Set-Cookie: sessionid=75eved1hfktbfrigiu063ny9dybltvma; httponly; Path=/
```

__

Edit 2:

Output of netstat -tulpn | grep nginx

```
netstat -tulpn | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22932/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22932/nginx
```

Comment: Have you added dns record?

Comment: what happens if you call `curl -D - http://foo777.domain.com`? Run it, then edit your question and paste the output to it. Tag (@tedder42) me if you want me to look at it again.

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715871/nginx-not-picking-up-site-in-sites-enabled

Comment: @LigoGeorge - I have tried that. The symlinks are created with absolute paths

Answer (score 0):

Just try making some syntax error in the configuration file and try nginx -t, to make sure that you are editing the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Alexey Ten, it turns out a new dns setting for foo777 had to be entered. This is so unlike Google App Engine's way. Thanks for the help Alexey.